# ChartJS: Invalid scale configuration for scale: xAxes

Tags: charts, chart.js

I get a strange error in ChartJS and have no idea how to fix it, due to the error I can't change anything about the scales.

My Code (Sensor.tsx):

```js
import { useParams } from "solid-app-router"
import { createSignal, createResource, onMount, createMemo, createEffect } from "solid-js";
import Chart from "chart.js/auto";

const numToSenor = {
    1: "temperature",
    2: "air_humidity",
    3: "soil_humidity",
    4: "photoresistor",
    5: "microphone",
    6: "ble",
    7: "gas",
    8: "co2",
    9: "batter_voltage",
}

let myGraph;
let chart

export const Sensor = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    const [sensortType, setSensortType] = createSignal(1);
    const [sensorData, setSensorData] = createSignal([]);
    const fetchURL = createMemo(() => `http://localhost:1234/sensor/${params.id}/${numToSenor[sensortType()]}`)
    
    createEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:1234/sensor/${params.id}/${numToSenor[sensortType()]}`)
        .then(raw => raw.json())
        .then(data => setSensorData(data));

    })
    onMount(() => {
        let canvas = myGraph.getContext("2d")
        chart = new Chart(canvas, {
         type: 'line',
         data: {
            datasets: [{ 
                  data: sensorData(),
                  label: "Temperature",
                  borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                  fill: false
            }]
         },
         options: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
               display: false
            },
            tooltips: {
               mode: "index",
               intersect: false,
            },
            hover: {
               mode: "nearest",
               intersect: true
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                  type: "time",
                  ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 20,
                    },
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "Point"
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "Value"
                    }
                }]
            }
         }
      })
    })
    createEffect(() => {
        chart.data = {
            datasets: [{ 
                  data: sensorData(),
                  label: "Temperature",
                  borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                  fill: false
            }]
         }
         chart.update();
    })

    

    return (
        <>
        <div class='w-full wp-2 overflow-y-auto h-screen' >
            {/* Header */}
            <div  class=" bg-slate-50 duration-200 m-6 p-2 border-b-3 border-light rounded-md flex ">
                SensorID: {params.id}
            </div>
            
            {/* Data Graph Picker */}
            <div class="flex mx-6 mt-12">
                <div onClick={() => setSensortType(1)} class={`${sensortType() == 1 ? "border-slate-400" : "border-light"} bg-slate-50 duration-200 mr-4 p-2 border-b-3  rounded-md flex hover:bg-slate-200`}>
                    Temperature
                </div>
                <div onClick={() => setSensortType(2)} class={`${sensortType() == 2 ? "border-slate-400" : "border-light"} bg-slate-50  duration-200 mr-4 p-2 border-b-3  rounded-md flex hover:bg-slate-200`}>
                    Air Humidity
                </div>
                <div onClick={() => setSensortType(3)} class={`${sensortType() == 3 ? "border-slate-400" : "border-light"} bg-slate-50  duration-200 mr-4 p-2 border-b-3  rounded-md flex hover:bg-slate-200`}>
                    Soil Humidity
                </div>
                <div onClick={() => setSensortType(4)} class={`${sensortType() == 4 ? "border-slate-400" : "border-light"} bg-slate-50  duration-200 mr-4 p-2 border-b-3  rounded-md flex hover:bg-slate-200`}>
                    Brightness
                </div>
                <div onClick={() => setSensortType(5)} class={`${sensortType() == 5 ? "border-slate-400" : "border-light"} bg-slate-50  duration-200 mr-4 p-2 border-b-3  rounded-md flex hover:bg-slate-200`}>
                    Loudness
                </div>
                <div onClick={() => setSensortType(6)} class={`${sensortType() == 6 ? "border-slate-400" : "border-light"} bg-slate-50  duration-200 mr-4 p-2 border-b-3  rounded-md flex hover:bg-slate-200`}>
                    BLE
                </div>
                <div onClick={() => setSensortType(7)} class={`${sensortType() == 7 ? "border-slate-400" : "border-light"} bg-slate-50  duration-200 mr-4 p-2 border-b-3  rounded-md flex hover:bg-slate-200`}>
                    Gas
                </div>
                <div onClick={() => setSensortType(8)} class={`${sensortType() == 8 ? "border-slate-400" : "border-light"} bg-slate-50  duration-200 mr-4 p-2 border-b-3  rounded-md flex hover:bg-slate-200`}>
                     CO2
                </div>
                <div onClick={() => setSensortType(9)} class={`${sensortType() == 9 ? "border-slate-400" : "border-light"} bg-slate-50  duration-200 mr-4 p-2 border-b-3  rounded-md flex hover:bg-slate-200`}>
                    Battery Voltage
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* Data Graph */}
            <div class=" block bg-slate-50 duration-200 m-6 mt-2 p-2 border-b-3 border-light rounded-md ">
                {numToSenor[sensortType()]}
                <canvas ref={myGraph}></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

I use SolidJS so don't wonder about that part and vite as the build tool.

Here are the error codes in the console,as you can see none of the axis parameters were apllied (for example no autoSkip on the x-axis labels)
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version you are using?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using V3 of chart.js while using V2 syntax for all of your options.

For example, the tooltip and legend should be configured in the plugin's namespace.

For the error you are getting, in v3 all scales are their own object in the scales object so no more separate arrays for the `x` and `y` axes.

For all changes please read the migration guide:

[3.x Migration Guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/getting-started/v3-migration.html#_3-x-migration-guide)

Comment: That link is also incorrect, correct link would  behttps://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/getting-started/v3-migration.html since master becomes latest so then your link will break too

Answer (score 1):

You need, from version 3 onwards, to remove 'Axes' from the name and also remove the brackets as below:

```
  options: {
       scales: {
            x: {
              type: "time",
              ticks: {
                autoSkip: true,
                maxTicksLimit: 20,
                },
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: "Point"
                }
            },
            y: {
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: "Value"
                }
            }
       }
```